# Problem with | operator in pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching

My first question here as I only got into *Mathematica* programming recently. Basically I have a large symbolic algebraic expression where I know certain variables with head pε appear with degree 2 in each term. So the terms look like this:

```
(...) pε[i, j] pε[k, l] + (...) pε[m ,n] pε[p, q] + ...
```

I want to pick out which of these appear in my expression, and I figured out this would do the trick

```
(Reap[expr /. patt : (x_pe y_pe | _pe _pe) :> Sow[patt] ;][[2,1]]) // DeleteDuplicates
```

which gives:

> {pe[4, 6]^2, pe[3, 6]^2, pe[2, 6]^2, pe[5, 6]^2, pe[3, 6] pe[4, 6], 
>    pe[3, 6] pe[5, 6], pe[4, 6] pe[5, 6]}

This however is missing terms because, when I ran two sets of pattern matches without `|`, I get more terms

```
(Reap[expr /. patt : x_pe y_pe :> Sow[patt] ; 
expr /. patt : _pe _pe :> Sow[patt] ;][[2,1]]) // DeleteDuplicates
```

> {pe[3, 6] pe[4, 6], pe[2, 6] pe[4, 6], pe[2, 6] pe[3, 6], 
>    pe[3, 6] pe[5, 6], pe[4, 6] pe[5, 6], pe[2, 6] pe[5, 6], pe[4, 6]^2, 
>    pe[3, 6]^2, pe[2, 6]^2, pe[5, 6]^2}

So I would like to know what's going on. In particular I imagine the first would be a lot more efficient if it worked properly.

Also feel free to give alternative ways of doing this. My choice of using `Reap, Sow` was one of efficiency but my of knowledge of the language is still small.

#### Edit

Based on the example given by @Federico I have constructed a small analogue where the difficulties are manifest, I use `Cases` because it's conceptually clearer

```
sum = Sum[pe[i, j] l[i, j] pe[j, k], {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}]
```

whose output is:

> l[1, 1] pe[1, 1]^2 + l[1, 1] pe[1, 1] pe[1, 2] + 
>    l[1, 1] pe[1, 1] pe[1, 3] + l[2, 1] pe[1, 1] pe[2, 1] + 
>    l[1, 2] pe[1, 2] pe[2, 1] + l[2, 1] pe[1, 2] pe[2, 1] + 
>    l[2, 1] pe[1, 3] pe[2, 1] + l[1, 2] pe[1, 2] pe[2, 2] + 
>    l[2, 2] pe[2, 1] pe[2, 2] + l[2, 2] pe[2, 2]^2 + 
>    l[1, 2] pe[1, 2] pe[2, 3] + l[2, 2] pe[2, 2] pe[2, 3] + 
>    l[3, 1] pe[1, 1] pe[3, 1] + l[3, 1] pe[1, 2] pe[3, 1] + 
>    l[1, 3] pe[1, 3] pe[3, 1] + l[3, 1] pe[1, 3] pe[3, 1] + 
>    l[2, 3] pe[2, 3] pe[3, 1] + l[1, 3] pe[1, 3] pe[3, 2] + 
>    l[3, 2] pe[2, 1] pe[3, 2] + l[3, 2] pe[2, 2] pe[3, 2] + 
>    l[2, 3] pe[2, 3] pe[3, 2] + l[3, 2] pe[2, 3] pe[3, 2] + 
>    l[1, 3] pe[1, 3] pe[3, 3] + l[2, 3] pe[2, 3] pe[3, 3] + 
>    l[3, 3] pe[3, 1] pe[3, 3] + l[3, 3] pe[3, 2] pe[3, 3] + 
>    l[3, 3] pe[3, 3]^2

So there are two types of terms those that contain `pe` squared and those that don't. Those that do are captured by

```
Cases[sum, _pe^2, Infinity]
```

those that don't require

```
Cases[sum, _ x_pe y_pe -> x y, Infinity]
```

So the question now is why does the following also work for the case with no `pe` squared?

```
(Reap[sum /. patt : (x_pe y_pe) :> Sow[patt]; ][[2,1]])
```

And a followup question, how would one capture the squared terms if *Mathematica* didn't collect them in a square? For example, if I had `pe[1, 1]l[1, 1] pe[1, 1]` can I construct a pattern to capture this? Or will it never happen due to `Times` having the `Orderless` attribute? I am thinking of a situation where `l[1,1]` is very large and *Mathematica* doeesn't order it.

Another question is can I combine both pattern matching cases in one with the use of `|`, and, if so, would that be more efficient?

Comment: Please include your `expr` in the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
sum = Sum[pe[i, j] pe[j, k], {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}]
Cases[sum, HoldPattern[_pe*_pe | _pe^2], Infinity]
```

Note that patterns are first evaluated, so, if you omit `HoldPattern`,
`_pe*_pe | _pe^2` becomes `_pe^2 | _pe^2`, which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it doesn't seem to be working I have tried

    (Reap[expr /. HoldPattern[patt : (_pe _pe | _pe^2)] :> Sow[patt] ;][[2, 1]]) // DeleteDuplicates

   (Reap[expr /. patt : HoldPattern[(_pe _pe | _pe^2)] :> Sow[patt] ;][[2, 1]]) // DeleteDuplicates

    (Reap[expr /. patt : (HoldPattern[_pe _pe] | _pe^2) :> Sow[patt] ;][[2, 1]]) // DeleteDuplicates

they all return the first result I gave with missing entries. I am guessing the problem comes with how | interacts with patt:

Comment: Why doesn't it work? It seems ok to me. The code you posted in the comment above is a mess... :/

Comment: Sorry was trying to format it properly but it doesn't seem to work in the commenting section. My issue is that my sum are terms that multiply the bits with _pe which I am trying to collect separately, your example with cases doesn't work with my expression as is.

Comment: Nevermind, got your solution to work, thanks so much!!!

Comment: ALthough I am still confused why my original attempt doesn't work

Comment: If you post the expression you are working with we could try to fix your original attempt.

Comment: I will try to get a small subset of the expression that  has the bahaviour of the whole thing